# Lambda Expression for Not In a Collection

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have 3 tables

### eTrip

Country | eProfile

### eProfile

Documents (collection of Document)

### Documents

Type | ExpiryDate | Country

I am trying to get a collection of eTrips in a search api. There are several conditions that need to be met for an eTrip.

Each employee can hold multiple documents (visas, passports, etc). For an eTrip to be valid we need to make sure the eTrip.Country != the country of a valid passport (future expiry date) document.

How can we write a lambda expression to accomplish this?

The code that I have so far is something like this

```
    var query = context.eTrip.AsQueryable();
    query = query.Where(e => e.validTrip == true);
    var docs = query.Select(e => e.eProfile.Documents);
        foreach (Documents d in docs)
        {
            if (d.DocumentTypeCode == "Passport" && d.ExpiryDate != null && d.ExpiryDate > DateTime.Now)
            {
               query = query.Where(e => e.Country != d.Country);
            }
        }
```

I need to write the filter for the country now and I am not sure how we can do it for a collection.

Comment: I think the [.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) method might be what you're looking for.

Comment: query = query.Where(e => e.Country != e.eProfile.Documents.???); The Documents is an iCollection. So basically what I need to do is e.Country != e.eProfile.Documents.Document.Country and Document.Type = 'Passport' And Document.Expiry is in future

Comment: You can continue to use Linq expressions within the Where clause. So you'd need to find the passport within the documents collection using the Where Linq extension method, then look at the ExpiryDate property.

Comment: But that is what I am trying to figure out. When I do e.eProfile.Documents. I am seeing the properties associated with a collection. I am not sure how I can access each document of type passport and a valid expiry date for that document and compare it's country with the trip country

Comment: Updated my code to include what I just came up with. I just need to figure out how to only include those that satisfy the if condition in the foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can extend your Where clause with an Any subquery on Documents

```
query = query.Where(e => e.validTrip == true && e.eProfile.Documents.Any(a=>a.DocumentTypeCode == "Passport" && a.ExpiryDate.HasValue && a.ExpiryDate.Value > DateTime.Now && e.Country!=d.Country));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
        // your part
        var query = context.eTrip.AsQueryable();
        query = query.Where(e => e.validTrip == true);
        var docs = query.Select(e => e.eProfile.Documents);

        // get countries for which there are no documents with future date
        var myCountryQuery = query.Where(x => !docs
            .Where(d => d.DocumentTypeCode == "Passport" && d.ExpiryDate != null && d.ExpiryDate > DateTime.Now)
            .Any(d => d.Country != x.Country)
            );
```